# Error while validating and publishing windows 8.1 universal project built with MobileFirst Foundation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, windows-8.1-universal

In MobileFirst Foundation, adding the JSONStore to the Windows 8.1 Universal environment will add the following files to the project:
Msvcr110.dll
Sqllite3.dll
JSONStoreWin8Lib.dll

To create a package and validate it for publishing, I open the .sln file in windows 8 native using Visual Studio, click on the project publish 
(project->store-create application package) to start the process.

The validation process failed with the error:
'msvcr110.dll  is not supported'
The error will occur only when taken through MS store validation.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

MobileFirst bundles the VC++ runtime for JSON Store along with Windows 8 project.

This is necessary for some devices (tablets) which have an OS without the runtime (usually old Win RT 8.1 operating system)

The issue arises due to the msvcr110.dll referenced in the project.
This is a OS runtime library  that is referenced in the MFP project with JSONStore enabled.

To solve this issue please perform the following:

1. Delete the msvcr110.dll reference from visual studio project
2. Delete the msvcr110.dll from the following locations
   a. {ProjectName}/windows8/native/buildtarget/ARM/msvcr110.dll
   b. {ProjectName}/windows8/native/buildtarget/x86/msvcr110.dll
   c. {ProjectName}/windows8/native/buildtarget/x64/msvcr110.dll
3. Add Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package (11.0 version) as a
   reference in the project. In the Visual Studio project, right click on
   references , add new reference , click Windows 8.1 -> extensions. Ensure
   Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package V11.0 is selected. If other
   versions are selected as well ,it's ok.
   Ensure 11.0 is selected and checked.
   4.Rebuild and deploy.